# Where to do a 'Rains Retreat' in South Korea?

Tags: personal-practice, zen, meditation-zazen, retreat

I would like to attend a 3 months "rains retreat" (Kyol-Che), in a Zen (Seon) temple in South Korea. I would have to go to a temple where they give instructions in English, though.

'Mu Sang Sa' Temple  (which I hope is way cheaper for monks) seems to organize two 3 months retreat a year. Do you know other places?

Answer (score 1):

In his book, "Confessions of a Buddhist Atheist", Stephen Batchelor, Spiegel & Grau, Random House, 2010, describes his experience of doing just this in 1981.  Batchelor's first Zen retreat was at [Songgwangsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Songgwangsa), under the guidance of Kusan Sunim, and he stayed until 1984, a year after Kusan Sunim's death.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Beware that [this article](http://www.gaia-images.com/photographe/songgwangsa/) suggests that few people at the temple speak English in depth (and according to his book, in 1981 Stephen Batchelor seems to have been the first English-speaker there). The article mentions Hyon Gak Sunim as notably English-speaking (but perhaps he too was only visiting Songgwangsa and not permanently there).

Answer (score 1):

There's [The Hwa Gye Sa International Zen Center](http://www.seoulzen.center/about-the-center). I know nothing of it but its web site (i.e. that it's "international", Zen, next to Seoul, and has retreats with an application form and an email address); and that in 2007 [Hyon Gak Sunim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rqzyPSevzA) was teaching there.

It also [a page with three or four links](http://www.seoulzen.center/links) to other places (one of which is Mu Sang Sa).